# Should I rewrite my code from ground up with async/await, or can I just use Task.FromAsync and TaskComplitionSource to wrap higher level classes?

Tags: async-await, c#-5.0

I have class that uses HttpWebRequest asynchroniously inside it and provides interface like this:

```
StartAsyncOperation(Action<TResult> onSuccess, Action<Exception> onError)
```

What profit will I get if I'll rewrite this class using HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync iside it, or I just can use TaskComplitionSource like here [Using the Task Parallel Library on an event-based asynchronous pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342170/using-the-task-parallel-library-on-an-event-based-asynchronous-pattern), and it will be ok?

Comment: Does your class use `Begin*()` / `End*()` (APM) or just the threadpool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `StartAsyncOperation` does in fact use asynchronous operations (e.g., `BeginGetResponse`/`EndGetResponse`), then there's not a huge benefit in rewriting it.

Doing a `TaskCompletionSource` wrapper for now is fine. Eventually you'll probably want to rewrite it to use `async` because years down the road the `onSuccess`/`onError` pattern is going to look very strange to developers who are used to `async`.

Answer (score 0):

If your code follows the [APM pattern (BeginMethod / EndMethod)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228963.aspx), then go ahead and use `TaskFactory.FromAsync` right away.

I would recommend not consuming `TaskFactory.FromAsync` but wrapping it in `Async` suffixed method that can have its implementation replaced in the future by **async/await**. This way you can refactor your code as needed and not just for the sake of **async/await**.